# Edit a file in-place in vim

Tags: vim

Normally, you don't actually edit a file in vim.  If you run `vim foo`, edit, write and quit, vim unlinks `foo` and creates a new file and a new link named `foo`.  But, if the file has more than one link, then `vim` actually modifies the file.  For example:

```
$ ls -i foo
19428852 foo
$ vi foo
$ ls -i foo
19428857 foo
$ ln foo bar
$ vi bar
$ ls -i bar
19428857 bar
```

I've been looking around for a way to actually edit a file, and it seems there are two choices.  Use `ed`, or use `vim` but ensure that there are at least two links to the file before I edit.  I suppose the question is academic, as it doesn't really matter that vim creates a new file if there is only one link, and vim seems to do the right thing if links are created while the editing is underway, but I'm curious:

is it possible to make vim always edit the file, and not create a new one?

Comment: Some reasons why it makes a difference... advantage of creating a new file and swapping the link: prevents other programs from seeing a partially written file. Advantage of writing the file in place: the fileschanged program (which uses fam) seems to see the change sooner (immediately, vs. 6 seconds or so delay when file is deleted and link swapped, for some reason... this is arguably just an idiosyncracy in fam or fileschanged)

Comment: If a single file is bind mounted, for instance - into a Docker container - then changing the file by creating a new file and swapping the link means the bind mount continues to point to the old file by inode ID. Writing to the file in place is the solution. The answers below helped me in this situation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check out the help for the `backupcopy` option and the notes on `crontab` in particular.  The short answer is

```
:set backupcopy=yes
```

Comment: Thanks.  I find that documentation unclear, though.  "When the file is a link the new file will not be a link".  WTF??!!  Every link is a link, and the only way to access a file is through a link!

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to tell Vim to use a backupfile to allow the original file to be safely overwritten, otherwise Vim would write to a new file and then rename it to replace the original.

And then tell Vim to write the backupfile nowhere. This way the regular write command will fail, and write must be forced.

```
:set noswapfile
:set backupcopy=yes
:set backupdir=''
:e big
(hit Crtl-C to stopo line count and syntax highlight)
(edit the file)
:w!
```

To really see what is going on at the file system level, I used inotify tools:

```
inotifywait -m -r /path/to/my_test_dir/
```

But be careful, this does not work well for very big files, for example, I was trying to edit a 10G file in place with this method and ended up with a truncated file of 1.5GB, and the rest of the data was lost. And Vim ended up using almost 2GB of RAM...

Other option would be to use MMap functions, eg. in a Python command line.

Answer (score 2):

Quick google shows this link - [Editing a hard link to a file](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Editing_a_hard_link_to_a_file). The command that controls that is

```
set backupcopy=auto,breakhardlink
```