# Is it possible to open our application at a specified time?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I want to do an application that auto Launches itself at a specified time and do its task. For example Anti Virus applications in Windows will launch every day automatically at a specified time given by the user and cleans the system. I searched fully in the net but can't able to get anything that does not violates sandbox. LaunchAgents looks promising but it is not supporting the sandbox. My question is it possible to do this kind of scheduling in OS X ? If it is possible may I know how to do this?

Comment: It should be possible: EyeTV uses this kind of mechanism to launch just before a scheduled TV recording starts. It even starts up the computer if needed.

Comment: @mouviciel : May I know which framework or class I have to use for this ?

Comment: I never needed it, so I didn't look for it. I just comment on my  experience as a simple user.

Comment: after some research, I found [Using cron on mac osx Mountain Lion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15395479/45249), [Schedule jobs using launchd](http://nathangrigg.net/2012/07/schedule-jobs-using-launchd/), and [Sandboxing and calling Launchctl](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/317446-sandboxing-and-calling-launchctl.html). Unfortunately, no answer in these.