# Running an application automatically every day

Tags: java, maven, parameterized

I have an application that tests web services. And I want to **run this application every day at 6 pm**.

I wonder if it is possible to do this **automatically**?

*For information: this application is developed with Java, JUnit parameterized tests, maven...,
  **OS**: Windows 7
 *

Comment: OS? is it a standalone application?

Comment: Os : windows 7 and yes it is a standalone application,but it has access to database and to web services.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create *[schedule task](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7)* in windows and *[cron job](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/)* in UNIX to trigger your application which test web services.

Comment: So I have to write a script that do "maven install" for example?

Comment: @Mouna you will have to initiate the application through schedule task as you initiate it using command prompt.

Comment: And on Mac OS X you have a choice between `cron` and `launchd`. Apple prefers `launchd` while some users prefer `cron`. See Apple's [doc on scheduled jobs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/bpsystemstartup/chapters/ScheduledJobs.html) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15395721/642706).

Comment: This is the best option if you want the program to just run briefly then exit.  If you want a process hanging around all the time and control when it runs via the Java code then a service is your best option.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
Date date = new Date();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int delay = hour < 18 ? 18-hour : 18- (hour-18);
System.out.println("Current Hour : "+hour+"\t"+"Delay For Next Mail: "+delay);
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
          System.out.println("run invoked");
             //do something
            }
        }, delay , 24, TimeUnit.HOURS);
```

Provided the server is up and running.

First create an instance of [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) which provides the method

```
public ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable command,
                                                  long initialDelay,
                                                  long period,
                                                  TimeUnit unit);
```

**Accordingly calculate the delay ,period and the TimeUnit and the task to be executed**

Comment: this is create an overhead on memory, the application will always be loaded in memory, if you restart your system, your application will be lost.

Comment: But my program does not run on a server

Comment: @Vishrant  `if you restart your system, your application will be lost.`It depends on your implementation and deployment

Comment: @Mouna well if you are going to implement as a standalone jar you have to implement the logic that the jar runs everyday at the specified time until the task is done

Comment: @M.Sharma if you set the schedule task, it will be managed by windows which is not lost.

Comment: **Crucial Tip** Be sure the `do something` in the `run` method catches all [Throwable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) (all Exceptions and Errors). If any exception or error reaches executor, it stops doing any more runs. See this [funny posting](http://code.nomad-labs.com/2011/12/09/mother-fk-the-scheduledexecutorservice/) (uses naughty words).