# How to start an applescript at a specific time

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to make an applescript that will be left running in the background and will only execute at a specific time once a week, any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using cron on mac osx Mountain Lion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15395479/using-cron-on-mac-osx-mountain-lion)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: The question does appear to be about programming; the questioner isn’t asking how to run a program once a week, but about how to keep a program running in the background and then act once a week. That’s likely to be a programming issue; in AppleScript, it’s usually going to be solved in an idle handler.

Comment: @Alta2017, perhaps some of the confusion would be removed by changing the title to “How to *repeat* an applescript at a specific time”, to better match the actual question.

Answer (score 4):

What you probably want is the [idle handler](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/conceptual/ASLR_about_handlers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH206-SW7). The idle handler is called when an AppleScript application is first opened (after it completes its “run” handler, if it has one, otherwise, immediately).

Whatever number the idle handler returns is the number of seconds to the next run of the idle handler; that is, OS X will take that number and then wait that many seconds before calling the idle handler again.

How this will work in practice will depend on how precise you need the “specific time” to be. You could, for example, just have it return 7*24*60*60 and every time the idle handler runs, it will also run again in exactly one week.

Or, you could check the current date (which includes the current time) every time the idle handler runs, and have the idle handler return 24*60*60, thus checking itself every day; or 60*60, checking itself every hour; or 60, checking itself every minute.

This is a very simple idle handler: it displays an annoying “Hello” sometime on Friday:

```
on idle
    -- if today is Friday, say something!
    set currentTime to current date
    if the weekday of currentTime is Friday then
        display dialog "Hello"
    end if

    --only check once a day
    return 24 * 60 * 60
end idle
```

This will check specifically for 5:00 PM on Friday; it will check against the current time every minute:

```
on idle
    -- if today is Friday between 5 PM and 5:01 PM, say something!
    set currentTime to current date
    set fivePM to 17 * 60 * 60
    if the weekday of currentTime is Friday then
        if the time of currentTime is greater than fivePM and the time of currentTime is less than (fivePM + 60) then
            display dialog "Hello"
        end if
    end if

    --only check once a minute
    return 60
end idle
```

Depending on your needs, you may wish to consider using a property to store the last time the script did whatever it was supposed to do; properties are maintained across runtimes and may be used to prevent double-execution after power failures or over daylight savings time boundaries.

Answer (score 3):

I actually think what you're trying to do is best suited for launch service. (see more information [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/bpsystemstartup/chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html)

Basically, on your Mac you configure a .plist file (example shown below) that you place in a designated directory on your computer. The settings of the plist file tell the computer when you want it to run and what action to take. In your case, you'll configure it to run once a week at your specified time and tell it to launch your script. The benefit to this approach is you don't have to worry about someone quitting the script, it doesn't have to be running at all times. It will launch at your specified time, do it's work and then quit.

Example .plist file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.namespace.script_name</string>
        <key>Program</key>
        <string>/Applications/script_name.app/Contents/MacOS/applet</string>
        <key>LowPriorityIO</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Nice</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>StartInterval</key>
        <integer>7200</integer>
   </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: that look like a great approach, any change you write a sample of running an AppleScript, for example named "startupscript.scpt"  Tuesday to Saturday (or whatever) at 05 AM ? also I wonder, will this definitely work if the user is logged out (or at least have the screensaver on)