# Extended file attributes and bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, attr

I encountered an interesting behavior in Ubuntu bash, that I can't entirely understand.
If I add extended file attribute to a file and then change it - attribute is dropped from file. Which from my point of view is ok.

```
user@user:~/tmp$ echo "aaa" > testattr
user@user:~/tmp$ setfattr --name "user.test" --value "Tested" testattr 
user@user:~/tmp$ getfattr --name "user.test" testattr
# file: testattr
user.test="Tested"
user@user:~/tmp$ vi testattr 
< change something in file and save it > 
user@user:~/tmp$ getfattr --name "user.test" testattr
testattr: user.test: No such attribute
```

But if I write something in file using bash - file attribute is left where it is.
Can anybody explain such behavior?

```
user@user:~/tmp$ echo "aaa" > testattr
user@user:~/tmp$ setfattr --name "user.test" --value "Tested" testattr 
user@user:~/tmp$ getfattr --name "user.test" testattr
# file: testattr
user.test="Tested"
user@user:~/tmp$ echo "bbb" > testattr
user@user:~/tmp$ getfattr --name "user.test" testattr
# file: testattr
user.test="Tested"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

vi is deleting edited file and replacing it with new one. That's why attributes are not preserved.

This is log of operations on the file.

```
$ mkdir test
$ touch test/file
$ inotifywait -m -r test
Setting up watches.  Beware: since -r was given, this may take a while!
Watches established.
# vi is now running in another shell
test/ OPEN file
test/ CREATE .file.swp
test/ OPEN .file.swp
test/ CREATE .file.swpx
test/ OPEN .file.swpx
test/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE .file.swpx
test/ DELETE .file.swpx
test/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE .file.swp
test/ DELETE .file.swp
test/ CREATE .file.swp
test/ OPEN .file.swp
test/ MODIFY .file.swp
test/ ATTRIB .file.swp
test/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE file
test/ OPEN file
test/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE file
test/ MODIFY .file.swp
test/ CREATE 4913
test/ OPEN 4913
test/ ATTRIB 4913
test/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE 4913
test/ DELETE 4913
test/ MOVED_FROM file     # old file moved
test/ MOVED_TO file~
test/ CREATE file         # new file created
test/ OPEN file
test/ MODIFY file
test/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE file
test/ ATTRIB file
test/ ATTRIB file
test/ MODIFY .file.swp
test/ DELETE file~
test/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE .file.swp
test/ DELETE .file.swp
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043534/edit-a-file-in-place-in-vim) to disable that behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. Actually I would rather try to figure out how to have attribute dropped if file is changed =)

Comment: @PāvelsReško You can use the same `inotify` library to detect modified files and drop attributes on them.

Comment: @PāvelsReško Actually `bash` shows the most expected behavior, it changes file content without removing and recreating it. `vi` behavior is not expected in this case.

Comment: @Gregorz As I know - capabilities in Linux are implemented using extended file attributes. So if I add a capability to a script of some sort and then somebody will change that script - he can use my capability. Which is not very secure from my point of view.

Comment: @Gregorz, actually "security.capability" attribute is dropped from file if file is changed. It seems that it is some sort of exception.