# Replicating "tail -f" with Python

Tags: python, generator, yield, tail, seek

According to [David Beazley's talk on generators](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/Generators.pdf), the following code should replicate the UNIX `tail -f` command:

```
import time
def follow(thefile):
    thefile.seek(0,2)
    while True:
        line = thefile.readline()
        if not line:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            continue
        yield line

f = open('followed.txt')
lines = follow(f)

for i in lines:
    print i
```

If I run this in a shell, it's doing "something", and indeed it locks up the IPython notebook, but it ain't printing out the contents of followed.txt. Why so?

Comment: **Clarification**: with the code running, I open followed.txt with Vim, add a line of arbitrary text, and save it. Still nothing gets printed.

Comment: Your method works for me.

Comment: How are you appending to `followed.txt`? The code above may not work if you are adding text to `followed.txt` using a text editor, since the text editor may not be appending to the original file -- it may be creating a new file and then renaming `followed.txt` to it...

Comment: The code you posted will work if you  `f = open('followed.txt', 'a')` and call `f.write` concurrently, or (on unix) if you append using something like `echo "some text" >> followed.txt`.

Comment: I used your code in windows 7 and editting the file with notepad++ and it worked perfectly

Comment: [How to edit a file inplace using Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11043534/190597)

Comment: @unutbu Thanks for the link; indeed it had not struck me that perhaps saving in a text editor/Vim was in fact creating a new file each time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried the script, it works.

You have to make sure your input file is **a growing file.** If not it is hanging and expecting new growing lines.

Here's a script keep writing line with timestamp into sample.csv every 5 seconds.

```
import os
import time
import datetime

while True:
    os.system("echo " + "sample line with timestamp:{0}".format(datetime.datetime.now()) + " >> " + " sample.csv")
    time.sleep(5)
```

Use your `tail -f` script to read it and you will see the output.

Comment: See my comment above.

Comment: @pyderman  you cannot add a line and save the file. It will create a new file with the same name

Comment: Makes sense; I wonder though how Mr E above was able to achieve it with a text editor.

Comment: @Pyderman Glad it helps. BTW, It is really good Slides, thanks for your sharing!

Comment: @haifzhan  That's not always true.  It depends on the editor and whether it uses copy-on-write.

Answer (score 2):

The `follow()` generator is only going to return lines that are written to the file **after** `follow()` was called.  The `seek(0,2)` puts the cursor at the **end** of the file, and then tries to read new lines from that point on.

`tail` usually outputs the last 10 lines by default.  If you wanted something like that

```
def follow(thefile):
    n_lines = 0
    # Seek to the end of the file
    thefile.seek(0,2)
    # Seek the cursor back one character at a time until you
    # reach the beginning of the file or 10 newlines are found.
    while n_lines < 10 and thefile.tell() > 0:
        # Go back one character and read it.
        thefile.seek(-1, 1)
        c = thefile.read(1)
        # Only go back 10 lines
        if c == '\n':
            n_lines += 1:
        # Reset the cursor position for the character we just read
        thefile.seek(-1, 1)

    while True:
        line = thefile.readline()
        if not line:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            continue
        yield line
```